# List of lists and insert

Tags: python, list, insert

`matrix1` is a list of lists. My code check if `matrix1[i][5]` and `matrix1[i+1][5]` contain consecutive numbers. If yes ok, if not insert a new list in i+1 coping from previous and change `matrix1[i+1][5]` value increasing it by 1. This is idea in my mind but in real world code not working. If `matrix1[i][5]=1` and `matrix1[i+1]=4` my code should add 2 list after the first and before `matrix1[i+1]` and change number so at the end I haven't hole between 1 and 4 but all consecutive numbers and results should be for 1 2 3 4. But with my code the result is 3 3 3 4.. Can anyone help me?

```
for i in range(0, len(matrix1)-1):
    if int(matrix1[i][5])==int(matrix1[i+1][5])-1:
        continue
    else:
        matrix1.insert(i+1, matrix1[i])
        matrix1[i+1][5]=int(matrix1[i][5])+1
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi i dont' understand your request... My code check if `matrix1[i][5]` and `matrix1[i+1][5]` contain consecutive numbers. If yes ok, if not insert a new list coping from previous and change `matrix1[i+1][5]` increasing it by 1. This is idea in my mind but in real world code not working. If `matrix1[i][5]=1` and `matrix1[i+1]=4` my code should add 2 list after the first and before `matrix1[i+1]` and change number so at the end I haven't hole between 1 and 4 but all consecutive numbers and results should be for 1 2 3 4. But with my code the result is 3 3 3 4...

Comment: This edit is clear enough now

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. When you have a list `a = [0, 1]` and say `b = a; b[0] = 100; print(a[0])`, you still get an output of `100`. Why? Because assigning a list to a variable in Python *doesn't copy that list!* Instead, it makes the new variable refer to the same memory as the old one, so that modifying one modifies them all. This is the mistake you made here: `matrix1.insert(i+1, matrix1[i])`. You can create a copy by a [bunch of ways](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/copy). I'm going to iterate over the list using a list comprehension <sup>just for the heck of it</sup> like so: `b = [x for x in a]`
2. It's a bad idea to modify a list (insert/remove items) inside the for loop that iterates over the list. Instead, it's better to create a *new* list that holds all the values you care about.

Suppose you have a `matrix1` like so:

```
matrix1 = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10],
           [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11]]
```

Now let's define another list `matrix2`, which will be empty for now

```
matrix2 = []
```

Now we're going to copy every row into the new matrix. And if `matrix1[i][5]` and `matrix1[i + 1][5]` are not consecutive, we're going to also insert *all* of the necessary new rows into the new matrix.

```
for i in range(0, len(matrix1)-1):
    row = matrix1[i]
    matrix2.append([x for x in row])
    if int(matrix1[i][5])==int(matrix1[i+1][5])-1:
        continue
    else:
        # Add rows from [i][5] + 1 to less than [i + 1][5]
        # The third argument handles the case when [i + 1][5] is less than [i][5]
        for j in range(matrix[i][5] + 1, matrix1[i + 1][5], (1 if matrix1[i + 1][5] > matrix[i][5] else -1)):
            newrow = [x for x in row]
            newrow[5] = j # Set col 6
            matrix2.append(newrow) # Add another row
# Finally, append the last row
matrix2.append([x for x in matrix1[-1]])

print(matrix2)
```

This gives the output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11]]
```

Or, a more straightforward way: we can simply get rid of the check for consecutiveness and just have the `for j` loop, so we insert as many rows as needed to take us from `matrix1[i][5]` to `matrix1[i + 1][5]`. If they are consecutive, we'll end up inserting only one row.

```
for i in range(0, len(matrix1)-1):
    row = matrix1[i]
    # In this case, we also want to add the [i][5] row.
    # Add rows from [i][5] to less than [i + 1][5]
    for j in range(matrix1[i][5], matrix1[i + 1][5], (1 if matrix1[i + 1][5] > matrix1[i][5] else -1)):
        newrow = [x for x in row]
        newrow[5] = j # Set col 6
        matrix2.append(newrow) # Add another row
# Finally, append the last row
matrix2.append([x for x in matrix1[-1]])
```